# Twitter page for Hinduism SE Promotion

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I've built a unofficial Twitter page for Hinduism.SE Promotion, I would like community inputs over

- Design
- Color Schemes
- Feeds *(Already Synced, will update every 30 mins with maximum of 5 posts)*
- Short Description *(Ummm, am bad with this so please suggest one)*

Twitter Page : https://twitter.com/Hinduism_SE

Source Files: http://decodingweb.com/collectibles/hinduism_twitter.zip

[image: Twitter Page of Hinduism SE]

Comment: I think SE makes Twitter promotion page by their ownself

Comment: @AnkitSharma No idea but I gave a shot

Comment: Design: I liked the Ganesha symbolism, but can you make it a bit more abstract? I mean without specific gods, and including Om and swatika. Or we can ask molee to design one for us.

Color Combo: I liked the color combination with red and *bhagwa*.

Comment: @VineetMenon Previously I tried ignoring symbols with logos question but some of them didn't liked, I'll try some scripture symbols or cave arts at the back, whats your opinion over that?

Comment: "at the back"? What does that mean? But I like the overall idea. Give it a go.. You may add alternate designs in the same post.

Comment: @VineetMenon yup will edit that out soon

Comment: @AnkitSharma There will be an official SE twitter account eventually (give it a few months, I'd say), but all that account will do is tweet popular questions every so often.

Comment: @senshin till then we have our own.

Comment: Correction - as of a few months ago, Stack Exchange stopped creating Twitter accounts for new sites. So yeah, if we want a Twitter account, Mr. Alien's one is the way to go.

Comment: I think changing the name from **Hinduism** to **HinduismSE** would be more suitable. Because, we are not going to tweet about Hinduism but just the questions that come up in our site.

Comment: @Dharmaputhiran SEO matters, so used a generalized word..

Comment: @Mr.Alien What about something like **Hinduism Q&A**?

Comment: @Dharmaputhiran yea that is fine, I will rename it

Comment: @Dharmaputhiran done, thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

I'm skeptical that this will be very helpful in terms of drawing people to the site - that's presumably why Stack Exchange stopped creating Twitter accounts for new sites - but it certainly can't hurt, so heck, let's do this.

#### Design

The background image you've used there looks a bit grainy. Is it possible to render that image at a higher resolution?

#### Short Description

I suggest something like this:

> Unofficial page for Hinduism.SE, a member of the Stack Exchange family of Q&A sites

This way, people who don't know what the ".SE" suffix means will have some idea of what's going on. (Then again, do people even read the descriptions? I barely use Twitter, so I don't really know.)

Comment: About the **Design**, yes, its because of Twitters image compression, it was even worse when I uploaded jpg, it looks better when uploaded a png, and yes, I'll edit the description with the one you provided, thanks for your inputs