# Twitter accounts for our main site

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Recently I saw a twitter account for [Academia SE](https://twitter.com/StackAcademia/). Then, I searched for such account for our main site and found an [unofficial one](https://twitter.com/Hinduism_SE) by [Mr.Alien](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179/twitter-page-for-hinduism-se-promotion), which is no longer active.

In this context, my doubt is that who maintains the official twitter accounts, if exists?

Comment: There won't be any official social accounts. The community should manage it unofficially, afaik.

Comment: Our unofficial Facebook page: https://www.facebook.com/hinduism.stackexchange. I can make someone admin on it if they are interested to manage it. I think we just have to re-activate the feed (_I tried till now but no luck_).